# Is there a way to toggle displayed target framework in VS 2022 Solution Explorer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, projects-and-solutions, multitargeting

I have a multi target C# project that targets .Net Framework 4.8 and .NET 7.0.
Some of my source code files are included only for one of the above target frameworks.
The Solution Explorer shows the project from the perspective of .NET 7.0.

My Question is:

Is it possible to switch this perspective so that I can see the include files from the perspective of a specific target framework that is specified in my project file?

My csproj file looks something like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net7.0;net48</TargetFrameworks>
    ..
    <EnableDefaultCompileItems>false</EnableDefaultCompileItems>
    <EnableDefaultContentItems>false</EnableDefaultContentItems>
    <EnableDefaultItems>false</EnableDefaultItems>
    ..
  </ProjectGroup>

  ..

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="sourcecode_A.cs" />
    <Compile Include="sourcecode_B.cs" />
    <Compile Include="sourcecode_C.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net7.0'">
    <Compile Include="sourcecode_X.cs" />
    ..
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net48'">
    <Compile Include="sourcecode_Y.cs" />
    ..
  </ItemGroup>
  
  ..

</Project>
```

The Solution Explorer only shows files (from Perspective .net 7.0)

- sourcecode_A.cs
- sourcecode_B.cs
- sourcecode_C.cs
- sourcecode_X.cs

Comment: Have you tried to achieve similar results by using solution configuration and conditional compilation symbols. You can define different solution configurations for each target framework and use conditional compilation to include or exclude specific sections of code based on the target framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the hint of @wenbin-geng I solved the problem as follows:

I added two more build configurations to my solution: net48_Debug and net7_0_Debug.

I modified my project file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFrameworks>net7.0;net48</TargetFrameworks>
  <TargetFramework Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='net48_Debug'">net48</TargetFramework>
  <TargetFramework Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='net7_0_Debug'">net7.0</TargetFramework>
  ..
  <EnableDefaultCompileItems>false</EnableDefaultCompileItems>
  <EnableDefaultContentItems>false</EnableDefaultContentItems>
  <EnableDefaultItems>false</EnableDefaultItems>
  ..
  <Configurations>Debug;Release;net48_Debug;net7_0_Debug</Configurations>
</ProjectGroup>
```

Now it is possible to switch the target framework by selecting a build configuration.

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.